# How do I put server-side webcam video on my web page?

Tags: php, html, video-streaming

How do I put server-side webcam video on my web page? I'm using PHP, JavaScript, and HTML5.

I have no need to seek or replay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right answer to your question depends a lot on your specific use case.

For the general user, an easy solution is to stream your webcam to a site like [ustream](http://www.ustream.tv), and then embed the ustream player for your channel in your website.

Answer (score 1):

This is through jsp you have to change server.jsp to php code

```
  <html>
     <body>
      <div id="mine">
       <video id="video" width="500" height="500" autoplay="true"></video>
       <video id="video1" width="500" height="500" autoplay="true"> </video>
     </div>

     <script type="text/javascript">
         var str;
        (function(){
          var video=document.getElementById('video'),
          vendorUrl =window.URL || window.webkitURL;
          navigator.getMedia=navigator.getUserMedia ||
                         navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                         navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                         navigator.nsGetUserMedia;
                         navigator.getMedia({
                         video:true,
                         audio:true
                     },function(stream){
                      video.src=vendorUrl.createObjectURL(stream);
                      str=vendorUrl.createObjectURL(stream);
                     video.play();
                     },function(error){
                         alert("error")
                     });
             })();

        var ajax=new XMLHttpRequest();
        function processresponse(){
             if(ajax.readyState===4){
                 var rse=ajax.responseText;
                 var vid=document.getElementById("video1");
                 vid.src=rse;
                 vid.play();
            }
        }
        function show(){
             ajax.onreadystatechange=processresponse;
            ajax.open("Post","server.jsp",true);
            ajax.send(str);

        }
         timer = setInterval(show,10000 );

       </script>
     </body>
   </html>
```

server.jsp....

```
   <%   
   InputStream is=request.getInputStream();     
    byte[] bt=new byte[1000];
     is.read(bt);
    String req=new String(bt);
   out.println(req );
    %>
```